# inserting hyperlink into sql database - php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I'm trying to insert a hyperlink into a mysql databse which will then be retrieved by the user  through a messaging system. I can't get the hyperlink to work; the output is just text saying "click here to respond".

So, when a user is invited to something(an event in this case), they will receive a message saying something like "Click here to respond." When the user clicks the link it will display the event. I echo'd this link on a page and I know it works, I just can't figure out how to get it to display once pulled fromt he database. It's being stored in a column that is of type varchar.

The inputs from code above this chunk have been sanatized using mysql_real_escape_string. Just thought I'd throw that out there before anyone mentions it.

```
$to = $userExplode[$i];
$from = "0";
$eventNumber = mysql_fetch_array($eventNum);
$title = "Event Invitation";
            $message =  '<a href= http:/localhost/loginsystem/viewevent.php?eventID = ' . $eventNumber['eventID'] . '> Click here </a> to respond.';
$sql = mysql_query("Insert INTO messages (title,message,to,from) VALUES ('New Message','$message','$to','$from')");
```

edit: I got it to work, it was tricky. I had to hard-code my messaging system to check if the system sent a message. Then it would echo the parts of the URL and insert the link after href="..."

Comment: You need to add quotes around your `href` attribute value.

Comment: Is the data inserted correctly into the database? How are you outputting it?

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry True although

Comment: To save on database space and not write http:/localhost/loginsystem/viewevent.php?eventID a million times, just save the event ID as a SQL entry, then call it in PHP with something like this: "<a href= 'http:/localhost/loginsystem/viewevent.php?eventID='<?php echo $var-from-database>> (Sorry if the syntax is off, typing from memory)

Comment: On second thought, how am I supposed to query the database if I have no "where" portion of my statement? For example "select eventID from messages where...." See what I mean, I don't know what I'm selecting from.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the `href` and give `http://` the full two slashes, not just one :P Other than that, post your code to output it.

Comment: I tried to make a link just to the homepage and it didn't work. I think it's an issue with hyperlinks in general, not just using variables.